# Bean validation only works for controller methods in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-boot, javabeans

Tried with code below, seems in Spring, bean validation only works for controller methods(those who annotated with @RequestMapping), plain methods won't trigger bean validation.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test-validate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String test(@Validated Obj obj){
    return "validation-works";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/test-local-method-validate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String test2(@Validated Obj obj){
    Obj obj = new Obj();
    localValidate(obj);//won't validate, though content is null
}

void localValidate(@Validated Obj obj){
    log.debug("entered");
}

//Model
public class Obj{
    @NotNull
    public String content = null;
}
```

if we call the first method: /test-validate, the validation would trigger, while for the second method: /test-local-method-validate, we call with a local plain method: localValidate, the validation doesn't work.

If it's true, how can I enable bean validation in plain methods?

Comment: And the question is?!

Comment: @MDeinum add the question in original question:
How can I enable bean validation in plain methods?

Comment: Without AOP trickery using AspectJ you cannot enable it. You can register a `MethodValidationPostProcessor` to enable this, but it will only work for external calls, not internal calls (due to the use of AOP proxies).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: it will not work in your current code because when calling `localValidate(obj)` you are skipping the Spring created proxy completely and this proxy is responsible for the validation part.

Options:

1. You could extract this logic to another, package protected scoped, Spring component, inject it to the controller and call it instead of your `localValidate` method,
2. Inject `org.springframework.validation.Validator` to your controller and call it manually